# How can I display a fullscreen image with a black background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I implemented the feature to display a fullscreen image when it is tapped. However this only enlarge the image but does not show it with a black background (the other elements of the view are still in the bakcground). How can I do this?

```
//Setup touch up inside of the imageview (in viewdidload)
    userPictImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    userPictImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewFullScreenTouchHandler:)];
    tapper.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [userPictImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];

//present a full screen image (without black background)
-(IBAction)imageViewFullScreenTouchHandler:(id)sender {
    //goto new ViewController and set the image
    UIImageView *imageView = userPictImageView;

    if (!imageIsFullScreen) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

         //save previous frame
         prevFrame = imageView.frame;

        blackView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [blackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:blackView];

         CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
         [imageView setFrame:frame];
         [blackView addSubview:imageView]; }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    imageIsFullScreen = TRUE;
          }];
        return;
     }
    else{
       self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
          [imageView setFrame:prevFrame];
                }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    imageIsFullScreen = FALSE;
                }];
         return;
       }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, or, probably better, build a UIView with a black background whose frame matches the view frame.  Make the image view a subview of that black view.

I'd do it something like this.  Create a method that I can call to zoom and unzoom the imageView.  To zoom, build a background view and attach the image.  To unzoom, do the reverse, and then destroy the background view.

Since the background view will be full screen, attach a gesture recognizer to it so the user can tap to dismiss.

```
- (void)setUserPictImageViewZoomed:(BOOL)zoom animated:(BOOL)animated {

    UIView *blackView = [self.view viewWithTag:128];
    BOOL isZoomed = blackView != nil;

    // if our current state (isZoomed) matches the desired state (zoomed), then we're done
    if (isZoomed == zoom) return;
    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;

    if (zoom) {
        blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        blackView.tag = 128;
        blackView.alpha = 0.0;
        [self.view addSubview:blackView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(unzoom:)];
        [blackView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

        UIImageView *zoomImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.userPictImageView.image];
        zoomImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        zoomImageView.tag = 129;
        zoomImageView.frame = [self.userPictImageView convertRect:self.userPictImageView.frame toView:blackView];
        [blackView addSubview:zoomImageView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            zoomImageView.frame = blackView.bounds;
            blackView.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    } else {
        UIImageView *zoomImageView = (UIImageView *)[blackView viewWithTag:129];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            zoomImageView.frame = self.userPictImageView.frame;
            blackView.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [blackView removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
}


- (void)unzoom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    [self setUserPictImageViewZoomed:NO animated:YES];
}
```

I tested this quickly in a simulator and it looked pretty slick.

Comment: I am trying to implement it (I added the code in the question). But how can I remove the view and return the image to the original position?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I set up the blackview in the viewdidload and then add/remove it? Or hidde/show it? How should I add and remove the UIImageView from blackView? It will be very helpful if you can provide me a basic example of what I should add in if(imageIsFullScreen) and else().

Comment: I have an extra question, if I want to do it with an scrollview of images, what should I change/add?

Comment: Keep a property of the selected image and use that instead of userPictImageView.  You may need to fuss with frames a little since the scroll view offset is arbitrary.  That might warrant a new question.

Comment: I tried several things but they are not working. I added a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915621/how-to-display-a-scrollview-of-images-in-fullscreen). I would really appreciate if you can help me on this too.